# Send image data through JSON as array of bytes

Tags: ios, json, wcf

I'm consuming JSON web service and I need to send image data through JOSN.
The JSON schema look like below, any idea how I can achieve this?

```
"image":[81,
            109,
            70,
            65,
            50,
            78,
            67,
            66,
            ]
```

I would appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use Base64 encoding to transmit image data? Do you have any control over the server side?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve here. Could you describe some use-case for that? How is data coming to you? Are you asking how to parse/compress/decompress to/from some image format? Are you asking how to determine the image format?

Comment: @RicPerrott I have tried Base64 but It did not work, and for the server side it is already integrated with a .net app using the format above and they want to use unified service.

Comment: @valid I have a UIImage that I converted to NSData and I want to send it to JSON service that receive image as format I provided.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to get an array of bytes from an Image, try this approach:

Get the data for the given image

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
// You can use UIImageJPEGRepresentation() if you need a jpg rather than a png
```

Then, use a method like this to return an NSArray of bytes

```
- (NSArray*) arrayOfBytesFromData:(NSData*) data
{
if (data.length > 0)
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:data.length];
    NSUInteger i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        unsigned char byteFromArray = data.bytes[i];
        [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&byteFromArray 
                                        objCType:@encode(unsigned char)]];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}

return nil;
}
```

Loop through the array and form your JSON from there.

Good Luck!